# How do you pass an array to a mako template?

Tags: python, templates, mako

I want to pass an array of strings to Mako's render method but this doesn't work:

```
from mako.template import Template

mytemplate = Template(filename="some.template")
str = mytemplate.render(first="John", last="Smith", nicknames=[
                        "JJ", "Johnny", "Jon"])
print(str)
```

some.template =

```
Hello ${first} ${last}
Your nicknames are:
% for n in ${nicknames}:
${n}
% endfor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a '%' line, you're writing regular Python code that doesn't need the escaping:

```
% for n in nicknames:
${n}
% endfor
```